# C# Console application does not print in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, printing

I have been trying to get a document to print on a Windows 8.1 machine using the following console application;

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Printing;

namespace BasicPrinter
{
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var server = new LocalPrintServer();

        Console.WriteLine("Default printer:{0}", server.DefaultPrintQueue.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Default spool directory:{0}",server.DefaultSpoolDirectory);

        var printQueue = server.DefaultPrintQueue;

        Console.WriteLine(printQueue.Name);

        Console.ReadLine();

        var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("c:/Printing/Test2.pdf");

        var job = printQueue.AddJob();

        job.JobStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        job.JobStream.Close();
        job.JobStream.Dispose();
        job.Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

I am developing on a Windows 7 machine using Visual Studio 2013. When I run this application on my machine it prints the document as expected. I then remote into  the Windows 8.1 machine, copy the the contents of the bin file from my Windows 7 machine (along with the test2 pdf file) and run it again from there.

The application runs, I see the name of the printer, when I look at the printer in device manager I see that it is spooling but then instead of printing it simply deletes the job.

I have checked that I am targeting "Any CPU", both machines are x64.

Why would this not work on the Windows 8.1 machine?

It is the only 8.1 machine I have access to.

Comment: Have you tried recompiling the code on the other machine? Just a thought.

Comment: It's a good idea, and no I have not tried it. The other machine does not have Visual Studio and I've not got the option of installing it.

Comment: are you trying to print silently? without displaying printdialog?

Comment: Yes, silent printing. No dialogs.

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/3e6ada37-a335-44ba-92fb-f8431e0ff79e/c-console-app-print-job-vanishes-in-windows-8-regardless-of-print-driver-used-works-in-windows-7?forum=w8itproappcompat - look here, seems you're not the only one who  faced same issue.

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 8.1 uses v4 print drivers. They require that the file that is added to the jobstream be a .xps, if not you get a [0 byte spool file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2779300)

I used word to create an xps file called Test3.xps then replaced

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("c:/Printing/Test2.pdf");
```

with

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("c:/Printing/Test3.xps");
```

This printed.